# How to redirect entire site using .htaccess except for specific URLs?

Tags: .htaccess

I have to redirect the entire website to a new domain.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/.*$ http://new.example/
```

Except for the URLs of the form `old.example/app/*` and `old.example/auth/*`

For example, I would like to prevent the redirect for URLs `/app/xyz` and `auth/login`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to redirect to the same URL on the new domain, not to the document root, as in your example (that would be bad for SEO and seen as a soft-404 by search engines).

Try the following, using mod_rewrite, at the top of your root `.htaccess` file instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to new domain except for URLs that start "/app/" or "/auth/"
RewriteRule !^(app|auth)/ https://new.example%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `!` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* negates the regex, so it's successful when the requested URL path does *not* start `/app/` or `/auth/`. `https://example.com` is the new domain and the same URL-path is used (ie `REQUEST_URI` server variable).

*Alternatively*, if the URLs you want to exclude from the redirect are quite long or plentiful then you may choose to use *conditions* instead to exclude the specific URLs. For example:

```
# Redirect to new domain except for URLs that start "/app/" or "/auth/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/auth/
RewriteRule ^ https://new.example%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If the old and new domains point to the same server then include a pre-condition that checks for the old domain. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.example [NC]
:
```

Comment: Thank you MrWhite for quick response. 
Actually my condition is like. I would like to redirect all the url to newdomain.com except oldomain.com/auth/* and olddomain.com/app/*. 
I just implemented your provided lines but still didn't worked.

Comment: The above directive specifically excludes both those URLs, so if you are still being redirected then make sure you are not seeing a cached response (your earlier 301 - permanent - redirect will likely have been cached by the browser). So, you will need to clear your browser cache before testing. The above is also a 302 (temporary) redirect - so you can check for this in the network traffic to see what is happening.

Comment: I cleared cache of browser and tested on different Browsers too. But still didn't worked for me. You can test the url. 
http://downloads.freeware.download/app/dashboard
http://downloads.freeware.download/auth/login

Comment: That URL appears to work "OK" for me - in that there is no redirect to another domain. `/app/dashboard` redirects to `/auth/login` on the same domain. (?) Although, having said that... it doesn't appear to redirect anything? Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: I want all the url's redirected to newdomain.com except /auth/ and /app/. I have implemented above provided lines but didn't worked for me. 

`olddomain.com => newdomain.com`
`olddomain.com/xyz => newdomain.com`

Comment: So, are you saying there is no redirection at all? If so, then _something else_ is going on. Do you have any other directives in `.htaccess`? Any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: I got idea from your answer and i did it. Thank you!
`RewriteRule app|auth  -  [L]
RewriteRule .* http://google.com [L,R=301]`

Comment: If that "works" then it suggests the URL being requested was not seen as `/app/` or `/auth/`? The regex `app|auth` checks for `app` or `auth` _anywhere_ in the URL-path!? (I don't see any redirect when visiting the site linked to above?)

Comment: Yes you are right. if app and auth exists any where in URL it don't redirects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209478/discussion-between-sohail-ahmed-and-mrwhite).

Comment: Ok, if that's the intention then you can just change the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ in my original directive from `!^(app|auth)/` to `!(app|auth)` - which effectively does the same as your additional `RewriteCond` (condition) directive.